# How to use siege to test Magento with user login?

Tags: login, users, magento

I have a Magento site running on CentOS 6 (Amazon EC2). I've installed Varnish cache and a FPC extension called PageCache to make Varnish work with Magento.
When I am not logged in, I check the reponse header of the site and notice that Varnish works with Magento, and the site is cached by Varnish.

But when I log in with email and password, it seems that Varnish doesn't cache Magento site. **So the response time is much longer when there's a user logged in**.

I need to test my site with Siege. I will test 1 user with 100 request by running command:

```
sudo siege -c1 -r100 http://54.254.183.85/
```

When I test Siege without logged in, i receive this result (response time 0.01s)

[image]

But the problem is, when I test Siege with a user logged in on my Magento site by adding

```
login-url = http://54.254.183.85/customer/account/login/ POST name=vanlinhpianist@gmail.com&pass=pianolangtu2908
```

to the `/etc/siege/siegerc` file then run the command `sudo siege -c1 -r100 http://54.254.183.85/` again, I receive the result

[image]

The response time is still 0.01s (very fast). So i think there are something wrong in the login-url configuration. When a user logged in, the response time must be longer because Varnish doesn't cache Magento site when a user logged in. Therefore, I want to ask how to use Siege to test Magento with user login?

Comment: Anyone know the answer please help me, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot do this type of test using siege test.

Also in order to effectively stress test the server it is better to use a tool that will actually emulate browser actions.

You can use a service such as http://loader.io, they do have a free account that you can use just to see if you can test what you need and then get the paid one to tests for longer periods of times (which is where you want to keep an eye at as performance will degrade overtime).

A open-source option would be https://artillery.io, you would need to start a cloud instance (AWS, etc) to run this test from there, since running from a local machine is not very reliable.

I am also in the process of testing the non-cached pages on a Magento 2 projects. I will share my artillery.io scripts on my github once done. Still working on those.